# Google Sheet Script Editor - setValues for array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I`m trying to replace old values with new values using setValues in Google sheet script.

The data is in the below link...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pSUVkxM9FhSNgizedHbY2MnYGTnC2iiYLfrWsoPmDks/edit?usp=sharing

I`m basically trying to remove first 14 characters and the last 12 characters under "Tracker" column

Below is the code I tried..

```
function URLReplacement() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("transformer");
  var rng = ss.getRange("G:G");
  var data = rng.getValues();
  for (var items in data)
  {
    var newer = data[items][0].substring(14)
    // Turn these strings into an array
    var newerr = newer.split(" ")
    // Turn this into 2 dimensional array to use setValues

    ss.getRange("G:G").setValues([newerr])

  Logger.log([newer]);
}
}
```

But now, I get errors with the setValues statement
Saying the range I set there do not match the data

What am I doing wrong here..?

Can anyone please provide me with suggestions / advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to convert from `IMAGE_SUFFIX_"http://google.com"<xxxnouse>"` to `http://google.com` at the column "G".
- The format of `IMAGE_SUFFIX_"http://google.com"<xxxnouse>"` is constant.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? The reason of your error is that `[newer]` is not 2 dimensional array for using `setValues()`. If this error was removed, the header is removed by overwriting the empty value. So I would like to modify as follows.

#### Modification points:

- When `getLastRow()` is used, the data size retrieved by it can be reduced from that retrieved by "G:G". By this, the process cost can be reduced.
- Header is not retrieved by `getRange(2, 7, ss.getLastRow(), 1)`.
- From the format of `IMAGE_SUFFIX_"http://google.com"<xxxnouse>"`, `split()` was used for parsing this value.
- The converted data was put by `setValues()`. By this, the process cost can be also reduced.

#### Modified script:

```
function URLReplacement() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("transformer");
  var rng = ss.getRange(2, 7, ss.getLastRow(), 1); // Modified
  var data = rng.getValues();
  var convertedData = data.map(function(e) {return e[0] ? [e[0].split('"')[1]] : e}); // Added
  rng.setValues(convertedData); // Added
}
```

#### Note:

- In your shared sample Spreadsheet, the sheet name is "Sheet1". But your script uses "transformer" as the sheet name. Please be careful this.
- If the format of actual values in your Spreadsheet is different from your shared Spreadsheet, this might not be able to be used.

#### References:

- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, This is doing exactly what I intended this to be. Apologies for the sheet name! Totally forgot about this.. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: @Jason1993 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Yup Thanks again :)